# beeline jdbc client - does it need Metastore JDBC connection details?

Tags: hive, beeline, hive-metastore

I have used hive CLI , that is "hive" ; upon reading a bit more, I came to know that "hive" cli is old one and the preferred way to interact with HIVE is using "beeline", which is a jdbc client, which connects to `hiverserver2`.

I have created a 5 node cluster and the "MetaStore database" (which is MySQL) is running on a physical server , with IP, say "11.22.33.44". (not writing the actual IP addresses)

The "hiveserver2" runs on a different physical server, 55.66.77.88 (not writing the actual IP addresses).

Now, when I want to connect to HIVE using "hiveserver2"  , it asks for the Database URL.

Is this Database URL the same which we can connect to "MetaStore Database" (in my case MySQL) ?

Why should it ask for Database URL? As per my understanding, it connects to "hiveserver2" (which isn't a database server), so shouldn't it ask for host, port number where hiveserver2 is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your hive server is running locally, you would access it like this

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

Replace localhost with your Hive server ip/server name, not the metastore

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://55.66.77.88:some_port -n someuser -p somepass
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, we need to provide the IP:PORT of the hiveserver2. But what about the user id and password? Is this the user id, password of the actual Database (for example, MySql) or which user id?  I read that hiveserver2 can forward request on behalf of client, so which user are we talking about? Can you help explain this?

Comment: @Curious The HiveServer2 does not share users with the metastore. The user accounts depend what credentials settings you've given to Hive, such as using Kerberos or LDAP, but they map closest to HDFS users, not database users

Comment: @cricket_007 : thanks for your comment. So clients which connect to hiveserver2 don't use the actual DB credentials; thx for clarification; and thx for answering my other questions too